# Why is implementing copy-paste in a touch screen based smartphone such a big deal?

Tags: quality, touchscreens

When Apple didn't implement copy-pasting on the iPhone since version 1, I had just assumed it was a UI issue (Eg. they were waiting until they figured out a good UI for it). Now however the idea is out there and Microsoft still released Windows Phone 7 without copy-paste functionality, promising it will be ready in a *few months*.

My question is: Why does this takes a few months to implement? Are there some technological challenges that are unique to programming for a touch screen that I'm not familiar with?  For that matter, what are the unique challenges in doing X in a touch screen app?

Comment: A few months. Lol. Sounds like a bad excuse to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a short item on tablet PC's on this week's [BBC Click](http://www.bbc.co.uk/click) following up from the previous week's show. The presenter made the comment that tablet PCs are more about **consuming** content rather than **producing** content.

If that is the thinking behind these devices then that **could** explain the lack of copy/paste. After all, if you are just reading text, watching video or listening to music what do you need copy/paste for?

**NOTE:** I don't think that these devices *should* be limited to just consumption. They have potential for being used in the production of content - it just needs the right app.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that it is simply a matter of priorities rather than a technical challenge. Copy-Paste is probably just not perceived as a critical feature for the product launch, and many other features simply beat it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Selection** is difficult.  My Android device has C&P of course, but selection is awkward and difficult.  Copy-paste is simple otherwise -- just a buffer, and a menu item.  So my guess is that because most copying happens when something's selected, that delays the feature.  Of course, if WP7 has selection that destroys my theory.  Does it?

Comment: I was pretty sure it did but I don't have a device on hand to confirm.